# Unable to view logcat for application on Nexus 5 (L Preview)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat, android-5.0-lollipop

*Whenever I start my application in Android Studio I dont get any logcat messages.*

If I switch over to the ADB log I can see this message being spammed a couple of times:

```
PropertyFetcher: AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for device
xxxxxxxxxx: device unauthorized. Please check the confirmation dialog on your device.
```

**However,** I have accepted this confirmation dialog. I have even revoked permissions and re-accepted them, with no result unfortunately.

This whole thing works flawlessly on any other device Ive tried on thus far.

Here's exactly what I see in Android Studio, where usually the app would be enlisted:

[image: This is what shows up next to the logcat]

**Im getting quite desperate over here, any idea on what might be wrong?**

Extras:

- I have developer mode on in the phone (tap build number etc).
- Debuggable is set to true in the app
- Tried uninstalling/reinstalling drivers
- Running Nexus 5 on L Preview, bootloader locked if that matters.

Edit:

Running Windows 8.1

Comment: Windows, MacOS or Linux?

Comment: @PaulRatazzi Windows 8.1